# Enabling GCP cloudresourcemanager gcloud config joe.bloggs@googlemail.com account does not match GCP project owner role joe.bloggs@gmail.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

Trying to run:

```
gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com —project=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
```

I get the authorisation error:

```
Enabling the Cloud Resource Manager API for project xxxxxxxxx... ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) User [joe.bloggs@googlemail.com] does not have permission to access project [xxxxxxxxx] (or it may not exist): Service '—project=xxxxxxxxx' not found or permission denied.
```

When I check the GCP policy troubleshooter it says that I have owner role in the project xxxxxxxxx. However you can see in GCP console my email address as joe.bloggs@gmail.com but in my gcloud config its joe.bloggs@googlemail.com. I have tried to change it to gmail.com in gcloud config and googlemail.com in project owner role but don't seem to be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set basic auth from your terminal:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Then set the project like below:

```
gcloud config set project <put your project id>
```

Then create a service account with owner setup

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create sa-name \
--description="sa-description" \
--display-name="sa-display-name"
```

Here `sa-description` is an optional description for the service account.
`sa-display-name` is a friendly name for the service account.
`project-id` is the ID of your Google Cloud project.

Then add owner policy:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-123 \
--member serviceAccount:sa-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/owner
```

Then create the service account key:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/key.json \
 --iam-account sa-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Then use this key:

```
export GCLOUD_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="~/key.json"
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file \
$GCLOUD_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Then enable:

```
gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com —project=$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
```

Comment: Thanks this help me out

Answer (score 0):

I understand there is an error in the gmail account used to login in gcloud, try using the ["gcloud auth list"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) command to verify the account used in gcloud, you can then use the ["gcloud auth revoke --all"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/revoke) command to logout from all acocunts in gcloud and after that try ["gcloud auth login email@address.com"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) to relogin using the right account.

If the owner email is wrong in cloud console and you are still able to login with that account, just [add another IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) with the right account as owner in the IAM menu, and then you can delete the misspelled account if necessary

Comment: Thanks Andres both answers help me get unstuck